# Get Tab (Parent) View from Within Tab Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, tabactivity, titlebar

I am wanting to access the titlebar that was setup in my tab activity from an activity that is within the tabhost. What do I use to call the parent? So far, I have this, but it does not work:

```
    View v = (View) getParent().getTitle();
    TextView title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.TitleLabel);
    title.setText("Custom Title Text Here");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was reference the TextView within the parentActivity:

```
    TextView title = ParentActivity.title;
    title.setText("Custom Title");
```

And of course, set the TextView to public static in the parent activity.